# Generic typing so that one method's result can be used as other method's parameter again

Tags: scala, generics, generic-variance

I have code that boils down to a Factory initializing an object and then using that object again to do additional operations:

```
trait Factory[T] {
  def initialize(): T;

  def finish(t: T): Unit;
}
```

As I understand this, the result of `initialize` should always be suitable to be passed to `finish` for any one `Factory` instance, regardless of `T`.

The factory itself is called at a point where it isn't known what `T` is:

```
object Minimal {
  object StringFactory extends Factory[String] {}
  val factories = Map[Int, Factory[_]](0 -> StringFactory)

  val factory = factories(0)

  // (1)
  val obj = factory.initialize()
  factory.finish(obj)

  // (2)
  def wrapper[T](factory: Factory[T]): Unit = {
    val obj = factory.initialize()
    factory.finish(obj)
  }
  wrapper(factory)
}
```

While variant (2) works, variant (1) doesn't:

```
type mismatch; found : Minimal.obj.type (with underlying type Any) required: _$6
```

but I can't figure out how to fix this. Is it even possible?

What does the compiler get by calling the `wrapper` method that it can't figure out itself? From my point of view, `obj`'s type should be `_$6`, as the compiler seems to name that capture of `_`. How can I make the compiler realize that without having to introduce a whole new method for it?

Comment: How can you .initialize() a null variable?

Comment: that's dummy, code, therefore the comment above that line. But the code doesn't compile. I'm talking about the compiler's behavior, not about an NPE

Comment: Well, in (1) you don't have a `Factory[T]` but a `Factory[_]`.

Comment: @JérômeMahuet I changed the code to avoid that misunderstanding

Comment: @Jasper-M I improved the question. Yes, it is a Factory[_], obviously. My experience with Scala's type inference is that it can figure out a lot, but it can't figure out that `finish`'s parameter is the same as `initialize`'s return type, despite it being in the trait declaration. I guess I could as well ask, why is `obj`'s type `Any` and not `_$6`?

Comment: do you need to generate or modify your set of factories dynamically? or you want to iterate over them? or why would you store them in a dynamic structure such as a Map?

Comment: The usecase is to provide de/serialization adapters for different types based on a type ID, specifically Protobuf extension IDs. Once set up, the map won't change anymore, but it needs to be set up once, and I need random access based on the ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Régis' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27960482/371191), I found out that the compiler infers `obj: Factory.T`. From there, it was a small step to combine this with dk14's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27960320/371191) to use `type TT = T`. The result is this, buth generic and statically typechecked, without introducing a wrapper method. Kudos to both!

To literally answer the original question

> From my point of view, obj's type should be _$6, as the compiler seems to name that capture of _. How can I make the compiler realize that without having to introduce a whole new method for it?

by giving `_$6` the explicit name `TT`. Of course, the methods then need to use that name as well.

```
trait Factory[T] {
  type TT = T
  def initialize(): TT;

  def finish(t: TT): Unit;
}

object Minimal {
  object StringFactory extends Factory[String] {
    def initialize(): TT = ""
    def finish(t: TT): Unit = {}
  }
  val factories = Map[Int, Factory[_]](0 -> StringFactory)

  val factory = factories(0)

  // (1)
  val obj: factory.TT = factory.initialize()
  factory.finish(obj)

  // (2)
  def wrapper[T](factory: Factory[T]): Unit = {
    val obj = factory.initialize()
    factory.finish(obj)
  }
  wrapper(factory)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Existential type looses its existentiality and becomes upper-bound after assigning its instance to val itself, so any way without such assigning will work, including:

```
 scala> trait Factory[T] { type TT = T; def initialize(): TT; def finish(t: TT): Unit;}
 defined trait Factory

 scala> val factory: Factory[_] = new Factory[Int] {def initialize = 5; def finish(t: Int) {}}
 factory: Factory[_] = $anon$1@31d0ca61

 scala> factory.finish(factory.initialize())
```

This will not work:

```
scala> val obj = factory.initialize()
obj: Any = 5

scala> factory.finish(obj)
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Any
 required: factory.TT
    (which expands to)  _$1
              factory.finish(obj)
                             ^
```

And this because scala will not see their types as equal (unless both are one same type member) as existentiality means that `intialize()` may return any subclass of Any, when `finish()` may accept any (but not always same) subclass of Any:

```
scala> trait Factory[T] { def initialize(): T; def finish(t: T): Unit;}
defined trait Factory

scala> val factory: Factory[_] = new Factory[Int] {def initialize = 5; def finish(t: Int) {}}
factory: Factory[_] = $anon$1@6e5da49

scala> factory.finish(factory.initialize())
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (some other)_$1(in value factory)
 required: _$1(in value factory)
              factory.finish(factory.initialize())
                                               ^
```

So the only way to bind input and output here is sharing type member between them.

Comment: Actually if you remove the type parameter this would work. See my answer

Comment: So introducing `type TT = T` fixes this when the compiler can stay within the class while typechecking, but that type is lost when the compiler has to give `obj` a definite type, I see... seems I have to introduce that method after all :\ thanks!

Comment: @ Régis Jean-Gilles there is no existential type in your solution: it's just same `Factory` everywhere

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles too bad I can only accept one answer, because a combination of both yours got me a solution, maybe one of you can incorporate that: declare `obj` as `val obj: factory.TT`!

Comment: Done. Though in this case inference works like a charm and the type annotation is not mandatory.

Comment: @dk14 check out my answer, it combines your and Régis ideas to solve the problem. Thanks, your input was invaluable!

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to entirely replace the type parameter with an abstract type:

```
trait Factory {
  type T
  def initialize(): T;

  def finish(t: T): Unit;
}

object Minimal {
  object StringFactory extends Factory { 
    type T = String
    def initialize(): T = ???
    def finish(t: T): Unit = ??? 
  }
  val factories = Map[Int, Factory](0 -> StringFactory)

  val factory: Factory = factories(0)

  // (1)
  val obj: factory.T = factory.initialize()
  // Or simply (relying on inference): val obj = factory.initialize()      
  factory.finish(obj)

  // (2)
  def wrapper(factory: Factory): Unit = {
    val obj = factory.initialize()
    factory.finish(obj)
  }
  wrapper(factory)
}
```

Comment: Close, but not quite what I meant. Check out my answer, and thanks bringing me on the right track!